# Generic method with generic class type constraint

Tags: .net, generics, c++-cli

I've got an generic interface which has a method with another generic type.
The constraint of the method should only allow types which are derived from the generic type of the class. I tried the following code and some other possibilities but none worked so far:

```
generic <class ObjectType>
public interface class IFoo
{
public:
    generic <class ObjectTypeInherited> where ObjectTypeInherited : ObjectType
    ObjectTypeInherited Test();
};

public ref class Derived : IFoo<System::Object^>
{
public:
generic <class ObjectTypeInherited> where ObjectTypeInherited :     System::Object^
    virtual ObjectTypeInherited Test()
    {
        return ObjectTypeInherited();
    }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    auto derived = gcnew Derived();
    auto nullString = derived->Test<System::String^>();
    if (nullString == nullptr)
            System::Console::WriteLine("Got a null string!");
    return 0;
}
```

I receive the following error with my code:

```
error C3766: 'Derived' must provide an implementation for the interface
```

method 'ObjectTypeInherited IFoo::Test(void)'

If I do change it to:

```
generic <class ObjectTypeInherited> where ObjectTypeInherited :     System::Object^
```

I receive a different error:

```
error C3284: the constraints for generic parameter 'ObjectTypeInherited' of function 'ObjectTypeInherited Derived::Test(void)' must match the constraints for generic parameter 'ObjectTypeInherited' of function 'ObjectTypeInherited IFoo<System::Object ^>::Test(void)'
```

Does anyone know how to implement that correctly?

edit: The *System::Object^* and *System::String^* classes are just used as an example here. Normally I do use 2 own ref classes like *MyObject* and *MyDerivedObject : MyObject*

Comment: Minor correction: Your where clause for the `Derived` method should be `where ObjectTypeInherited : System::Object`, without the `^`, but that still gives the same "constraints must match" error. I'm not sure why that error's still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all 
`generic <class ObjectTypeInherited> where ObjectTypeInherited : System::Object^`.
should be
`generic <class ObjectTypeInherited> where ObjectTypeInherited : System::Object`.

No **`^`** sign here.

And then the fun begins...

Somehow the `C++\CLI` compiler does not wish to understand that a class does not have to be generic in order to implement the `IFoo<ObjectType>::Test`. So I created a workaround for this strange problem.

You can use `System::Object` instead of `MyObjectType`. I used the `MyObjectType` just for versatility.

```
public ref class MyObjectType
{
};

generic <class ObjectType>
public interface class IFoo
{
public:
    generic <class ObjectTypeInherited> where ObjectTypeInherited : ObjectType
    ObjectTypeInherited Test();
};

//All the magic is here. Somehow the C++\CLI compiler does not wish to
//understand that the DerivedBase class does not have to be generic in order
//to implement the IFoo<ObjectType>::Test. As you can see the Whatever type
//name is never used. Although without it the compiler gives the C3284
//error.
generic <class Whatever>
public ref class DerivedBase : public IFoo<MyObjectType^>
{
public:
    //Why not make use of explicit syntax just because we can.
    generic <class ObjectTypeInherited> where ObjectTypeInherited : MyObjectType
    virtual ObjectTypeInherited Test() = IFoo<MyObjectType^>::Test
    {
        return ObjectTypeInherited();
    }
};

//In order to overcome the fake genericness of DerivedBase I provide
//another successor.
public ref class Derived : public DerivedBase<Object^>
{
};
```

I do not have any in-depth knowledge of either the Roslyn compiler or C++\CLI but to my mind this seems to be a bug.

If I do the same with the C# managed code, it should look as simple as this. And this is where I would stop myself. Even without any strange compiler behavior managed declarations are easier to maintain on the C# side than C++\CLI.

```
public class MyObjectType
{
}

public interface IFoo<ObjectType>
{
    ObjectTypeInherited Test<ObjectTypeInherited>() where ObjectTypeInherited : ObjectType;
}

public class Derived : IFoo<MyObjectType>
{
    //Explicit
    ObjectTypeInherited IFoo<MyObjectType>.Test<ObjectTypeInherited>()
    {
        return null;
    }

    //Implicit
    public ObjectTypeInherited Test<ObjectTypeInherited>() where ObjectTypeInherited : MyObjectType
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me since I get the following error:
    error C3225: generic type argument for 'ObjectType' cannot be 'System::Object', it must be a value type or a handle to a reference type

Comment: Your #1 is incorrect, that raises error C3225 "must be a value type or a handle to a reference type", as Cosmo said. With the `^` added, your code still gives error C3284, the constraints of Derived::Test must match the constraints of IFoo::Test.

Comment: This might be an issue with VS versions; which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @DavidYaw Thanks for the notice. I tried VS2015 with the all new modern Roslyn and there seems to be an issue. I suggested the solution,

Comment: @Zverev Eugene yes I'm also using VS2015. I also came up to a similar solution with the help of C#, where it's indeed easier. I just tried your solution now, and I'm not sure how you figured out about the "magic" but it's finally working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Cosmo I submitted a bug report to Microsoft regarding your problem: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2820295/c-cli-implementing-a-generic-method-of-a-generic-interface-give-compiler-error-c3284